# Angular jqlite child show

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I trying jqlite for show some elements but for the moment i have problems with
childs to show the content when the mouse is over.
I will put the code that i trying and the original with jquery.

```
  <li ng-mouseover="ProfileIn()" ng-mouseleave="ProfileOut()">
        <div class="face-container" id="carles" >
            <div>
                   <p>This is a description about the employee, and fact about something"</p>
            </div>
        </div>

</li>
```

The code working with jquery

```
   $(".face-container").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".face-container").mouseenter(function () {

            $(this).children("div").show();

        });
        $(".face-container").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).children("div").hide();

        });
    })
```

The code Not working that i trying with jqlite

```
    $scope.ProfileIn = function () {
angular.element(this).children('div').show;

    }
    $scope.ProfileOut = function () {

        angular.element(this).children("div").hide();
    }
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Angular Element Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

> children() - Does not support selectors

Therefore this line (below) in your code will not work, because the `children` function does not support selectors.

```
$(this).children("div").show();
```

You can only use children like so:

```
$(this).children();
```

Since `.children()` address the direct / immediate descendant, it's possible that it may do what you want (unless you have a mix of other direct children elements).

If you need advanced selectors, or other jQuery functions, you can absolutely use jQuery with Angular.  From the [Angular FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):

Does Angular use the jQuery library?

> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the
>   application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your
>   script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the
>   subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.
>
> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer
>   might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

So - note that you have to use **jQuery 2.1 or above**.

Comment: And i can do this with angular?

Comment: and without jQuery?. I would like to use Angular only.

Answer (score 1):

On my opinion use `ng-mouseover/ng-mouseleave` just for show/hide children elements is too heavy for performance (because they call a lot of $digest() cycle). More suitable would be old good css pseudo-class `:hover`.

```css
[hover-example] {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

[hover-example] > div {
  display: none;
}

[hover-example]:hover > div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li hover-example>
        <div class="face-container" id="carles" >
            <div>
                   <p>This is a description about the employee, and fact about something"</p>
            </div>
        </div>

</li>
```